# Adding page number serially to multiple pdf file

Tags: pdf, page-numbers

I have 200 PDF files (chapters of a book). I want to add page number to them.

the first PDF should have page 1-7, the second pdf 8-12, and so on.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: On which OS are you?
With LaTex you can import all... From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225567/116815) or [this other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269195/116815) for example... There are many online service too... You can use `pdfunite file-1.pdf file-2.pdf  ... file-200.pdf  out.pdf`

Comment: I do not want to unite the pdf files. I want them to stay separate. But I want to add page number to them sequentially in one go.